# Parameter in url not found

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I have the following URL for example: "http://localhost:3001/invoice/PfucXP7SGmReUxEBjE0Q". But the I can't get the parameter :invoiceId.

I use the following Link action to visit the page:

```
<Link to={`/invoice/${transaction.uid}`} activeClassName="current">
<Button type="button" color="primary" className="btn-sm btn-rounded" onClick={() => {}}>
     View Details
</Button>
</Link>
```

In my detail page I have:

```
const InvoiceDetail = (props) => {
    const [chk1, setchk1] = useState(true);

    let {  invoiceId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(invoiceId);
    }, [props.success]);
}
```

The parameter invoiceId is printer as undefined.

My UserRoutes is setup as :

```
const userRoutes = [
{ path: "/invoice/:invoiceId", component: InvoiceDetail },
];
```

My router is setup as :

```
return (
                <React.Fragment>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        {authRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                            <NonAuthmiddleware
                                path={route.path}
                                layout={NonAuthLayout}
                                component={route.component}
                                key={idx}
                            />
                        ))}

                        {userRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                            <Authmiddleware
                                path={route.path}
                                layout={Layout}
                                component={route.component}
                                key={idx}
                            />
                        ))}

                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
```

Code from my middleware looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Redirect, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const Authmiddleware = ({
                            component: Component,
                            layout: Layout
                        }) => (
    <Route
        render={props => {
            if (props.location.pathname === "/checkout") {
                return (<Component {...props} />);
            } else {
                // here you can apply condition

                if (!localStorage.getItem("authUser")) {
                    return (
                        <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}}/>
                    );
                }

                return (
                    <Layout>
                        <Component {...props} />
                    </Layout>
                );
            }
        }
        }
    />
);

export default withRouter(Authmiddleware);
```

Anyone an idea why the invoiceId is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the other variables by rest :

```
const Authmiddleware = ({
                            component: Component,
                            layout: Layout,
                            ...rest
                        }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        if (props.location.pathname === "/checkout") {
            return (<Component {...props} />);
        } else {
            // here you can apply condition

            if (!localStorage.getItem("authUser")) {
                return (
                    <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}}/>
                );
            }

            return (
                <Layout>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </Layout>
            );
        }
    }
    }
    />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always the little annoying details.. Remove the curly brackets (braces) in

```
let {  invoiceId } = useParams();
```

It should be

```
let invoiceId = useParams();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get an empty {}

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams - they're destructuring the param out of an object, removing the braces won't help

Comment: You can always check what the params are by doing a console.log(props.match.params). The parameter you are looking for should be props.match.params.invoiceId;

Comment: That object is empty aswell

Comment: I assume then that it is a problem with properties inheritance. You use two middlewares in your routing, NonAuthmiddleware and Authmiddleware. If you do a console.log(props) in the appropriate middleware you should see the required params under match.params. You should pass the routing params to the child component (i.e. < InvoiceDetail />) there. If you need help with that add the code from the middleware in your answer as well.

Comment: I updated my question, If I print out the props values in the auth middleware I got:

Comment: location: {pathname: "/invoice/1202-2393-2393-2039", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
match: {path: "/", url: "/", params: {…}, isExact: false}

Comment: from a quick look you seem to be passing the properties correctly to the component. What do you get when if you do a console.log(props.match.params. invoiceId) inside the component?

Comment: The params object is always {}, the object looks like match:
isExact: false
params: {}
path: "/"
url: "/"